# Routing WebForm to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, routes, url-routing

I want to redirect Asp.net [ WebForm ] to Mvc View or Mvc View to WebForm vise versa in different solution

Routing between MVC to WebForm

How can I do this

[image]

Please let me know if any solution there

Thanks you !!!!